# Are there any LaTeX commands (including in packages) where the argument will be in math/text mode based on context?

Tags: macros, package-writing, documentclass-writing, parsing, big-list

As I work on the parser for finl, I'm contemplating how I'm dealing with command parameters and wondering if my current setup is sufficient.

Right now, a parameter has a type which would either be parsed text or parsed math. Thinking about most commands, an argument would be always treated as one or the other, for example, there are the trivial cases like `\mathrm`'s argument will always be treated as math while `\textrm`'s argument will always be treated as text (and likewise for `\sqrt`, `\section`, and most others).

Now obviously, a user could easily do something like:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ m }{#1}
```

which is a trivial case of the argument will be treated as whatever its context demands, but in general, are there practical applications of this sort of context-aware handling of a parameter?

Comment: For instance, `\tikzmarknode` from the `tikzmark` `tikz` library checks whether you are in math or text mode, and if you are in math mode it will find out in which one. But in this case, it only inherits the ambient mode for the node contents.

Comment: In base LaTeX for example `\underline` accepts both math and text as argument, `\underline{a} \underline{$\beta$} $\underline{x} \underline{\alpha}$` all work. This is defined as `\ifmmode \@@underline {#1}\else $\@@underline {\hbox {#1}}\m@th $\relax \fi` I'm not sure if this is the kind of thing you are looking for but there are several more such commands I think, in base and in packages.

Comment: anything defined using `\TextOrMath` but that should be pretty rare

Comment: The `tabularray` package makes the disputable choice to eventually use `tabular` if `tblr` is called in text mode and `array` if `tblr` is called in math mode.

Comment: Iirc `\phantom`, `\hphantom` and `\vphantom` internally use `\ph@nt` for detecting math-mode and doing `\mathph@nt` or `\makehh@nt`. Iirc the command `\text` of the amsmath-package also checks for math-mode for deciding whether in math-mode to use `\text@`, adjusting font-sizes in case of sub/superscripts etc or - not in math-mode - to use `\mbox`.

Comment: Ah, the `\phantom` case is the real killer here. `\textcolor` has an implicit expectation that it's used in text (and thus a user might expect `\mathcolor` for math mode in analogy to, e.g., `\textrm`/`\mathrm`), and `\underline` was math-only for a long time and for finl I'd prefer something like `\textul` for underline but the various phantom commands are useful enough in both modes to require the ability to inherit the surrounding environment's parsing mode.

Comment: And it also occurs to me that I might want to also use that for the macro-definition parsing mode as well so that the rules for parsing macro-definitions will also be applied when a user defines a user command that calls some other macro. This would be a less-explicit case but would impact implementation of the parser in the same manner as having `\phantom` inherit math/text mode from its surroundings.

Comment: @DonHosek Why not have distinct commands -- the command for phantoms in math-mode raising an error if used in text-mode and the command for phantoms in text-mode raising an error if used in math-mode? This way people would be urged to know what kind of thing (math or text) they are currently working on. :->

Comment: @UlrichDiez Largely to reduce cognitive load. A LaTeX author should be able to pick up finl very quickly (LaTeX *programmers* will find most of their skillset inapplicable though). Also, one of the side effects of finl is that because it's written in Rust, I can compile to webasm which means, among other things, that it could be used as a replacement for mathjax/KaTeX for typesetting math in HTML and because of this (and the aforementioned ease of transition from LaTeX) means that math in particular should be as compatible as possible.

Comment: Also, being able to use the parser to parse existing LaTeX documents is a desirable thing.

Answer (score 5):

One example in the core distribution is `\textcolor` it may not be the best design but unlike `\textsf` `\textcolor` doesn't enforce text mode so

```
\textcolor{red}{a+b}  $\textcolor{red}{a+b}$
```

sets the first a+b as text and the second as math. However I'd say that this isn't a good example to follow.

Note that this is actually like your trivial `\foo` example, it doesn't actively test for math, it just allows the argument to fall through.

Comment: For `\underline` this behavior is the same I think.

Comment: @Marijn to the user, although underline is a math-only primitive so the latex `\underline` unlike `\textcolor` tests for math mode and adds math if it is not already in math

Comment: I mean that `\underline{a+b}` in text mode typesets `a+b` in text mode and `$\underline{a+b}$` typesets `a+b` in math mode.

Comment: @Marijn yes that's what i meant  with the initial agreement "[yes], to the user" but the final comment in my answer doesn't apply, this is a case that actively tests for math mode (actually it's quite a good example of that you coudl add it as another answer

Answer (score 3):

As user ABC says in the comments, the `\tikzmarknode` command from the tikzmark package sets its contents in the ambient mode.  It first does a test for whether we're in math mode and then uses `\mathchoice` to select the right style.  The aim is for it to be transparent to the user, a bit like your `\foo` command, but because it has to put its argument in a box then it has to be a bit more complicated internally.  The `\subnode` command from the same package does the same.

Answer (score 1):

There are commands that switch their expected input based on a separate command. For example the `stackengine` package defines the commands `\stackText` and `\stackMath` to switch the input for all the stacking commands (text is the default).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackunder{a}{b} \stackunder{$a$}{$b$} $\stackunder{a}{b}$
% $\stackon{\alpha}{\beta}$ % error

\vspace{5mm}
\stackMath
\stackunder{a}{b} \stackunder{$a$}{$b$} \stackunder{\alpha}{\beta} $\stackunder{a}{b} \stackunder{\alpha}{\beta}$
% \stackunder{$\alpha$}{$\beta$} % error
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that, somewhat surprisingly, `\stackunder{$a$}{$b$}` after `\stackMath` is typeset in text mode, because `\stackMath` adds a layer of math mode to the arguments that cancels out the existing one. Indeed in this mode `\stackunder{$\alpha$}{$\beta$}` results in an error.

And the other example from comments with `\underline`:

```
\underline{a+b} \underline{$\alpha+\beta$} $\underline{a+b} \underline{\alpha+\beta}$
```

all work, where the argument `a+b` is typeset as math inside math mode and as text outside math mode.

Comment: Although this is a scenario that I have no desire to emulate in finl.

Comment: @DonHosek Stackengine is a fairly popular package afaik, you wrote in another comment that you are interested in being able to parse existing LaTeX documents so I think this is something that you will encounter sooner or later. I must admit that, while I have used stackengine a number of times, I did not know about `\stackMath` before writing this answer, so I was using text input only (or specified math mode manually with `$`) and you are of course free to impose restrictions on the input for your parser - but I do expect that such a restriction will cause problems at some point.